# setState doesn't work in onSubmit function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

In this component, the `setState()` doesn't work after firing an async onSubmit function.

```js
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        
      this.state = {
        addingProduct: false
      }
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
      
    async onSubmit(formData) {
      const { addProductToServer } = this.props;
      
      this.setState({addingProduct: true});
      
      await addProductToServer(formData);

      //this doesn't set state to false    
      this.setState({addingProduct: false})
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what would be the expectation and elaborate more on how it doesn't work? Thank you!

Comment: I make a condition in render()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to destructure your props inside a function, that should come inside the render method. This is my attempt to simulate what you're trying to do.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const name = "Mathew";
export default class StackOverflow extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   addingProduct: false,
   server: []
 };
 this.addProductToServer = this.addProductToServer.bind(this);
 this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

addProductToServer(data) {
 return this.state.server.push(data);
}
async onSubmit(formData) {
 this.setState({ addingProduct: true });
 await this.addProductToServer(formData);
 this.setState({ addingProduct: false });
}

render() {
 // const { addProductToServer } = this.props
 console.log("server", this.state.server);
 console.log("addingProduct", this.state.addingProduct)
 
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Hello StackOverflow</h3>
     <p>{this.state.server.map((item, index) => (
       <li key = {index}>{item}</li>
     ))}</p>
     <button onClick={() => this.onSubmit(name)} type="submit">
       Submit
     </button>
   </div>
 );
}
}
```

This works.  And this is it in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-fast-c7m2z?file=/src/App.js)